# how to add custom fonts into a pdf through mpdf library using php yii framework

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf, font-family

I am using mPdf to convert html to pdf, in that pdf I want to give style font family. I follow the following instruction but its not working for Pdf though that font is working for other html file.

1-> I downloaded the font and copy the .ttf file into mpdf\ttfonts directory.

2-> Then I add :

```
"Futura-condensed" => array(
        'R' => "._ufonts.com_futura-condensed-regular.ttf",
    ),
```

under `$this->fontdata`

3-> then I used this in html file as inline :

```
<div style="width:30.5%; font-family:Futura-condensed; border-left: 5px solid #ddd;float:left;padding-left:15px; font-size:18px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
Total Readers
  <div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width:30%; margin:10px 0px; "></div>
    <p style="font-size:25px;">
    <b><?php echo '$26,923'; ?> </b>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the space b/w  step 2 , there must be no space

Comment: eg . $this->fontdata = array(
    "opensans" => array(
    'R' => 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf'
    )